# How do I make the Kotlin compiler treat warnings as errors?

Tags: kotlin

I have a Kotlin project where I'd like to have Kotlin warnings treated as errors. How can I do that?

Comment: In what build system, or IDE?  the answer might be different.  (I've never seen this option available, but to be sure be clear about in what build system this would be applicable)

Comment: Do you have the source of this project on Github? Are you using Gradle and Intellij?

Comment: @JaysonMinard it's using Gradle as the build system

Comment: @JaredBurrows https://github.com/jeffcharles/visitor-detector. A very early and still in development version. Yes and yes to Gradle and Intellij.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since Kotlin 1.2, the command line argument `-Werror` is supported. In Gradle, it's named `allWarningsAsErrors`:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors = true
}
```

Comment: Which block of `build.gradle` does this need to be added to?

Comment: @karl I think this should be on the top level. Please refer to the official documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#compiler-options

Comment: Thanks. From the docs, for future reference: for an Android project, the task name will include the build variant (i.e. `compileDebugKotlin`), but you can add it to all tasks by using `tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all { kotlinOptions { ... } }`

Comment: For Android: inside `allprojects` block of project level `build.gradle` file, add:
`tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all { kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors = true }`

Answer (score 11):

With recent versions of the Android Gradle plug-in, one can simply do this:

```
android {
    kotlinOptions {
        kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors = true
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This does not appear to be currently available in the Kotlin command-line help, or arguments available to the Kotlin compiler:

[K2JVMCompilerArguments.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/58e93d5e1bb547c8a7e398587b6851ccf6372326/compiler/cli/cli-common/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/arguments/K2JVMCompilerArguments.java)

and

[CommonCompilerArguments.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/58e93d5e1bb547c8a7e398587b6851ccf6372326/compiler/cli/cli-common/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/arguments/CommonCompilerArguments.java)

But some people in Gradle do things like this to scan logging of the compiler to know when a warning was generated.  [How to fail gradle build on Javadoc warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519085/how-to-fail-gradle-build-on-javadoc-warnings)

Within the IDE Plugins available for Kotlin (Intellij IDEA and Eclipse) there is no such option.

You should file a feature request (or check if one already exists) in [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) which has all the issue tracking for the Kotlin project.  And if you do so, please post the issue here so it can be tracked.

Comment: Feature request filed at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10563

Comment: Writing something in Gradle in the meantime is a reasonable idea. It's not high enough priority for me to justify the effort for that right now but I'll consider it in the future.

Comment: they schedule this improvement to 1.2? why there is no any VOTE button there

Answer (score 2):

If you are using android use this instead. In Android we don't have compileKotlin but rather compileDebugKotlin, compileReleaseKotlin, etc. So we have to loop through them and add this configuration to all of them.

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors = true
    }
}
```

Comment: For AndroidStudio 3.5, I put the above block within `allprojects` block at top level of ./app/build.gradle file, and that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

With the Kotlin DSL:

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending [LiorH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60297759/823738), here's kotlin DSL if you want to enable the warnings as errors only for release builds:

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors = name.contains("Release")
}
```