# Why do unreachable statements method not result in a compilation error?

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm only a Kotlin newbie, but after I had lost some time because of it, I was wondering... why the following code does not result in compilation error since the second return in `hello()` or the print("ciao") in `hello1` are clearly unreachable? (I'm confident that for other compilers, e.g. the Java compiler, this will be an error.)

```
fun main() {
   print(hello())
   print(hello1())
}

fun hello() : Boolean {
    return true // 1st return, this is always returned
    return false // 2nd return, unreachable
}

fun hello1() : Boolean {
    return true // 1st return, this is always returned
    print("ciao") // unreachable print
}
```

To be fair it gives a warning, but I'd like to have an error when such situations occur. Is there a way to make it an error?

Comment: That isn't illegal, so it isn't an error. Your IDE should have emitted a warning though. If it didn't, check the warning settings.

Comment: You can make _all_ warnings into errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562200/how-do-i-make-the-kotlin-compiler-treat-warnings-as-errors. Not this one separately, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Unreachable statements don't result in compilation errors in Kotlin, because it's a [language design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280787/unreachable-code-error-or-warning). Java language designers decided for it to be an error, but [not every language should agree with them](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/unreachable-code-after-return-statement-compiles/5490).

Scala, another JVM language, takes same approach as Kotlin, and reports unreachable code as warning:

```
object Main extends App  {
  println(a() && b())

  def a(): Boolean = {
    return false
    return true
  }

  def b(): Boolean = {
    return true
    return false
  }
}
```

[At some point, unreachable code was an error](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2256), but Kotlin team decided against it.

Now, as was already mentioned in the comments, you can turn all your warning into errors passing `-Werror` flag to Kotlin compiler. There's not specific flag for `UNREACHABLE_CODE` warning, though. You can try and request it, though, using [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT?q=UNREACHABLE_CODE).